# How to send messages in imo.im automatically using Python? I could not find imo.im api on the Net

Tags: python, api, whatsapp, skype, google-hangouts

I want to send news using imo.im api but after a long research I could not find it on the net. I have googled it, nothing is useful, please anybody help. I suppose imo.im does not support api officially like whatsapp.
[this is a imo.im pc program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI8oe.png)